# What are the things to be noted while creating a payment page?

Tags: php, html, curl, payment-gateway

I am creating a payment page for accepting payments from my clients. Currently I am using a payment gateway for transaction with PHP. The form data is posted using cURL to the payment gateway.

What are the security measures I should take to prevent threats and hackers? I am already using SSL.

Comment: @SLaks Im already using ssl.

Comment: Don't save or even request any sensitive information (most notably credit card numbers) on your own website. Let your payment gateway provider handle as much as possible. Then very carefully read the instructions and best practices for your particular payment gateway provider about how to integrate their service. This depends heavily the provider(s) in question. Use a test account to test success scenarios (payment got through) as well as failure scenarios (payment was cancelled, rejected, deferred, ...) Once again consult your payment gateway provider's information on how to do this.

Comment: @wkampmann Everything is sent to the payment gateway provider according to their specs.The part is good.But I would like to know about the security measures I should take.Like session management,timeouts..Can you please advice me on that,how it should be?

Comment: That concerns the security of your entire site, not only the specifics for payment handling. It's a huge subject. If you want to learn more, have a look at [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/). They are a trusted reference and have have lists of [security principles](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Principle), [attack types](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack), and so on.

Comment: @wkampmann Thanks you!I will refer to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use session for your pages.You can set auto session time out on the payment page